# Chamar Método C#

Tags: c#

Olá, estou com um projeto em andamento onde tenho uma tela de cadastro de funcionários. Preciso deixar a borda do `TextBox` vermelha caso haja algo de errado no preenchimento do mesmo.
Tentei de várias maneiras e nenhuma deu o resultado que esperava.
Encontrei esse código na internet, mas, não sei como chamar o método na condição.

Método

```
private void DrawRectangle(Graphics g, Rectangle rect, float penWidth)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark, penWidth))
    {
        float shrinkAmount = pen.Width / 2;
        g.DrawRectangle(
            pen,
            rect.X + shrinkAmount,
            rect.Y + shrinkAmount,
            rect.Width - penWidth,
            rect.Height - penWidth);
    }
}
```

Condição caso o campo esteja vazio.

```
if (txtNomeFuncionario.Text == string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show("O campo Nome parece estar vazio.");
    txtNomeFuncionario.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    // Preciso chamar o método DrawRetangle aqui
}
```

O método e a condição estão na mesma classe, desculpe a falta de conhecimento, mas sou novo nessa linguagem.

**@EDIT** Com o código abaixo eu quase consegui o resultado que queria, mas não ficou perfeito como a borda original.

```
txtNomeFuncionario.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f),
    txtNomeFuncionario.Location.X,
    txtNomeFuncionario.Location.Y,
    txtNomeFuncionario.Width,
    txtNomeFuncionario.Height);
```

Resultado do código acima
**Imagem 1**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Imagem 2**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Tente isso:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        textBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 2.0f), textBox1.Location.X, textBox1.Location.Y, textBox1.Width, textBox1.Height);
    }            
}
```

Note que `CreateGraphics()` é um método do formulário onde encontra-se o textBox1.

1. Retirei as Bordas;
2. Desenhei um retângulo exatamente no lugar das bordas;

Imagem com outras alternativas como informado no comentário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse código eu já tentei usar, infelizmente a borda fica deslocada, vou editar a pergunta e colocar uma foto da diferença entre a original e a borda com esse código. Além de deslocar aparentemente aumenta o tamanho do campo.

Comment: @GiovaniRodrigo, colando duas `TextBoxs` juntas, pude perceber a diferença. Vou efetuar umas alterações e fazer alguns teste para ver se consigo um resultado satisfatório. De ante mão existem outras possibilidade,eu por exemplo uso `.backgroundColor` no evento `Validating`, e tbm ainda existe um componente chamado `ErrorProvider`. Caso um dos dois interesse, só falar.

Comment: Testei `ErrorProvider` e pelo que entendi é apenas ícone de erro, não me interessou. Acho que independente do evento que eu use, para alterar a cor da borda do `TextBox` vai dar esse problema chato de aparência. Queria alterar apenas a cor da borda, `backgroundColor` seria a cor de fundo do `TextBox` eu acho.

Comment: Coloquei imagem sugerindo alternativas. é um exemplo bem simples, mais você pode usar de varias maneiras para validar um campo. exemplos: no `Leave, Validating, Validated`.

Comment: Então, é o primeiro `TextBox` que eu quero, mas o problema é que como ele é seguido de mais alguns `TextBox`, se comparar você percebe a diferença. Vou adicionar mais imagens.

Comment: @pauloricardo, gostei da resposta, não sabia desse erro do ícone, amanhã mesmo vou tentar implementar em meus projetos.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que usar o Evento Paint do `Form`. Deve ser algo assim:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNomeFuncionario.Text))
            DrawRectangle(e.Graphics, txtNomeFuncionario.DisplayRectangle, 1);
    }

    private void DrawRectangle(Graphics g, Rectangle rect, float penWidth)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark, penWidth))
        {
            float shrinkAmount = pen.Width / 2;
            g.DrawRectangle(
                pen,
                rect.X + shrinkAmount,
                rect.Y + shrinkAmount,
                rect.Width - penWidth,
                rect.Height - penWidth);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Como esse código verifica se o campo está vazio? Pois da maneira que está ai, nada acontece.

Comment: poderia invalidar o form, para forçar o paint. Não sei qual é melhor, fazer isso ou criar um novo Graphics. A solução demonstrada pelo Paulo Ricardo parece mais adequada